# Linker error with shared_ptr_base.h and gnu-libstdc++ 4.9 / 4.8

Tags: android-ndk, eigen, google-project-tango, eigen3, gcc4

I try to compile
https://github.com/personalrobotics/OpenChisel/tree/master/open_chisel
to use it for rendering on a [google tango device](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/)

I've tried to compile it for Android 4.4, ndk r10e and NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 (gcc 4.9) with the following flags:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -fopenmp -w
LOCAL_LDLIBS = -llog -lGLESv2 -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib
```

Including the latest Eigen Version 3.2.8

I tried it also with NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8 and older Eigen Versions.

But I always get for the ChunkManager.cpp file the following linker errors:

1. > Eigen/Eigen/Core
   >   (Unknown) In file included
   >   Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h: In instantiation of 'void Eigen::aligned_allocator::construct(Eigen::aligned_allocator::pointer, const T&) [with T = std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>; Eigen::aligned_allocator::pointer = std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>*]':

This is just an information but maybe it tells someone something

2. > android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/alloc_traits.h
   >   Information:(253, 4) :_Require::__construct_helper<_Tp, Args>::type> std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>; _Args = {const Eigen::aligned_allocator}; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u> >; std::_Require::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::type> = void]'
3. > android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/alloc_traits.h:399:57:   required from 'static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>; _Args = {const Eigen::aligned_allocator}; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u> >; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>)(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = ]'
   >   android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:620:37:   required from 'std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, _Tp*, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = chisel::Mesh; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator; _Args = {}; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
   >   android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1090:35:   required from 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator; _Args = {}; _Tp = chisel::Mesh; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
   >   android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr.h:316:64:   required from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator; _Args = {}; _Tp = chisel::Mesh]'
   >   android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr.h:588:39:   required from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::allocate_shared(const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = chisel::Mesh; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator; _Args = {}]'
   >   OpenChisel/open_chisel/src/ChunkManager.cpp:105:79:   required from here
   >   Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:733:9: error: use of deleted function 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace(const std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>&)'
4. > android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr.h
   >   (Unknown) In file included
   >      _Sp_counted_base(_Sp_counted_base const&) = delete;
   >      ^
   >    class _Sp_counted_ptr_inplace final : public _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>
   >          ^
5. > android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h
   >   Information:(494, 11) 'std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (_gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace(const std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace, (_gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   >   Error:(203, 7) error: 'std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>::_Sp_counted_base(const std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>&) [with _gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (_gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]' is private
   >   Error:(494, 11) error: within this context
   >   Error:(494, 11) error: use of deleted function 'std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>::_Sp_counted_base(const std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>&) [with _gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (_gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]'
   >   Information:(203, 7) declared here
   >   make: * [app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/rgb_point_cloud_builder/*/*/*/*/_/third-party/OpenChisel/open_chisel/src/ChunkManager.o] Error 1

I'm completely lost. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that combination of using Eigen and shared_pointer c++11 causes the errors.

Luckily there is a [patched version of chisel](https://github.com/stetro/OpenChisel/tree/master/open_chisel) which uses boost shared pointer instead.